# Where should I ask questions which are partially coding related?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I had questions which were related to coding Ruby on Rails (programming) and also related to a service like `google-oauth` (service).

So mostly these questions were not completely related to a programming section. Asking for service configuration related question, but related to specific framework like Ruby on Rails was a little tedious to know where it should be posted.

Even I could not get any answer from Stack Overflow and answers available on Google Cloud were not exactly describing with respect to framework like Ruby on Rails.

Where do these questions actually belong?

Comment: May be ask at [SE Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I will ask there and delete this one. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ under what tag, this question should be there?

Comment: They also keep language tags, and probably something about service configuration.

Comment: Could you give a sample link to the question? I suspect it actually is multiple questions in one that belong in different places.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev thanks for attention but i deleted that question so I just posted description in my question. It was about rails application integration with google auth but for company having number of domains.

Comment: @ray Well, that's not enough to say with confidence which points from https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic apply, so I can't answer then.